# Download excel in browser || Django

Tags: python, django, http, xlsxwriter

```
def excel(request):
    ans = request.POST.getlist('ans[]')
    ans_final=[]
    rows = request.POST.get('rows')
    for each_ele in ans:
        each_ele = each_ele.split('.')
        each_ele[0] = each_ele[0][:-2]
        each_ele[1] = each_ele[1][:-2]
    fin = each_ele[0]+' - '+each_ele[1]
    ans_final.append(fin)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/Desktop/status.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Test_Data')
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    for i in range(len(ans_final)):
        worksheet.write(0, i,ans_final[i],bold)

    row_index=1
    row_count = int(rows)
    while(row_count):
        col_index=0
        for each_ele in ans:
            worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, eval(each_ele))
            col_index += 1
        row_index += 1
        row_count -= 1


   workbook.close() 
   return JsonResponse({'ok':'ok'})
```

As seen in the above function in my **views.py**, when a button(**Download Excel**) is clicked in the UI, the request is sent to this function and I am generating an excel and saving it in **desktop folder** for now.

How do I make this excel download in the browser itself in UI  for the user when "**Download excel**" button is clicked instead of saving it in a specific path.

**Note** :- I am using xlswriter module for excel generation.

Comment: it is up to the browser how to handle files. But you have to make sure the header gets the right content_type, so the browser knows what filetype it downloads.

Answer (score 3):

Write your workbook into a `BytesIO`, then return the data as a response:

```
from io import BytesIO
# ...
output = BytesIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
# ...
workbook.close()
return HttpResponse(
  output.getvalue(), 
  content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  headers={'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=status.xlsx'},
)
```

Comment: I am getting error like "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
"

Comment: Ah, sorry. You can elide that parameter. I'm on mobile right now so can't do it sanely at the moment :)

Comment: The response is HTTP 200 from the backend, but in the ajax, its going into error section. Any suggestions how to prevent this?

Comment: You never mentioned AJAX in the original post. How are you making the request?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I am sending the data through Ajax....i kept datatype as 'json'....but the repsonse text is a string with special characters

Comment: Yes, Excel files are binary data. You'll need to either send the request as regular POST, or handle the binary data in your Javascript and simulate a download using e. g. `URL.createObjectURL()`